# Can Unified Memory Migration use NVLink?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I want to check whether unified memory migration (as previously discussed in this [page](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/) ) across different GPUs can now leveraging the NVLink for the later version of CUDA and GPU architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unified memory migration can use NVLink.

For a unified memory allocation, this would typically occur when one GPU accesses that allocation, then another GPU accesses that allocation.  If those 2 GPUs are in a direct NVLink relationship, the migration of pages from the first to the second will flow over NVLink.

In addition, although you didn't ask about it, NVLink also provides a path for peer-mapped pages, where they do not migrate, but instead a mapping is provided from one GPU to another.  The pages may stay on the first GPU, and the 2nd GPU will access them using memory read or write cycles which take place over NVLink.